# Drawable is not printed correctly in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a listview that displays the same clickable icon several times. I tried many ways, including a custom adapter with layout inflater but failed... At this point my ListView displays numbers instead of the icon. Can you help me please? here is my code

```
public class UserSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

static ArrayList<Integer> arrayOfIcons = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_selection);

    arrayOfIcons.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {arrayOfIcons.add(R.drawable.edit);}

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfIcons);
        ListView listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersListView2);
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //TODO                    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't do anything in onResume method, that's why I didn't share it

And my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/usersListView2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The print is correct. You are creating a list of integers and passing it to an adapter of integers that puts it in a textview. You need to understand the basics first. What R.drawabe.edit is an int that is the id of the drawable. You need to get that drawable or set it on an imageview as resouce first. Google some listview tutorials and you will get going in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy, I suggest you to create a custom adapter:

1) create your list_item:

In res -> layout create a new file named **list_item.xml**. It contains only one imageView inserted into a ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

2) In your **activity_main.xml** you have to inser your listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewIcon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

3) Now you have to create a new class call, for example, **IconAdapter**, where you create your custom adapter:

```
    public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Integer> iconIDList;

    /**
     *
     * @param context = activity context
     * @param iconIDList = list with icon's id
     */
    public IconAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> iconIDList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.iconIDList = iconIDList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return the size of my list
        return iconIDList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        //inflate my view
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        //istantiate my imageView
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);

        //set imageView's icon
        imageView.setImageResource(iconIDList.get(i));

        //return my view
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

4) Now in your **MainActivity**, put all together:D

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Integer> iconIDList;
    IconAdapter iconAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //istantiate my components
        iconIDList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewIcon);
        iconAdapter = new IconAdapter(this, iconIDList);
        int myIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background;

        //populate the list with icon's id
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            iconIDList.add(myIcon);
        }

        //set my custom adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(iconAdapter);

        //set clickListner to the elements of my listView
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                //i is the index of the clicked element
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click on element n. " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I hope that can help you!!! Good job!! If you have a question, comment my answer!!

Comment: It works fine ! thanks a lot for your answer, i can understand my mistakes now.

Comment: Hi again, now I want to add a list of names in my ListView, but with one listener for the name clicked and one for the icon clicked. I would add a TextView in my xml, set the text in my adapter, but I don't know how to handle two different listeners in a single ListView element. Can you give me some clues?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you ask me how to add one listener for the name (textView) clicked and one for the icon clicked.

1) modify your **list_item.xml** file. Now we can use:

- a LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout;
- a textView;
- a ImageButton instead of ImageView.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" > <!--this is very important to detect click-->

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textViewIcon"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:gravity="left|center"
      android:text="TextView"
      android:textSize="24sp" />

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButtonIcon"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

2) Is better if you create a class that contains your data. We can call this class **IconData**:

```
    public class IconData {

    int iconID;
    String text;

    //constructor
    public IconData(int iconID, String text) {
        this.iconID = iconID;
        this.text = text;
    }

    //getter and setter
    public int getIconID() {
        return iconID;
    }

    public void setIconID(int iconID) {
        this.iconID = iconID;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

3) Now we have to change our **IconAdapter**.

- We'll add an Interface to detect clicks on the ImageButton;
- We'll change the list's data type;
- We'll instatiate the newest TextView and ImageButton:

  ```
  //create custom adapter -> I extend my class using BaseAdapter
  public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  //create an interface to comunicate the clicks on the imageButton
  public interface MyIconAdapterInterface {
      void setOnClickListnerMyImageButton (int position);
  }

  Context context;
  //change the list's name and data type
  List<IconData> iconIDTextList;
  MyIconAdapterInterface myIconAdapterInterface;

  /**
   * @param context = activity context
   * @param iconIDTextList = list with icon's id and text
   * @param myIconAdapterInterface = the interface that mainActivity will implements
   */
  public IconAdapter(Context context, List<IconData> iconIDTextList, MyIconAdapterInterface myIconAdapterInterface) {
      this.context = context;
      this.iconIDTextList = iconIDTextList;
      this.myIconAdapterInterface = myIconAdapterInterface;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      //return the size of my list
      return iconIDTextList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int i) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
      return 0;
  }



  @Override
  public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

      //inflate my view
      if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater;
          inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
      }

      //istantiate my imageView and textView
      ImageButton imageButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonIcon);
      TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewIcon);

      //set imageView's button
      int image = iconIDTextList.get(i).getIconID();
      imageButton.setImageResource(image);

      //set text
      String text = iconIDTextList.get(i).getText();
      textView.setText(text);

      //setOnclickListner on my imageButton
      imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              //pass the position of my clicks to the myIconAdapterInterface
              myIconAdapterInterface.setOnClickListnerMyImageButton(i);

          }
      });

      return convertView;
  }
  ```

  }

4) Finally we have to change the **MainActivity.java**'s code:

- implement our class with the new interface that we have create in our IconAdapter;
- modify our list data type;
- pass the newest list and the interface to the IconAdapter;
- implement the interface's methods.

  ```
  //I implement my MainActivity with IconAdapter.MyIconAdapterInterface. I create this interface
  //in the iconAdapter class 
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IconAdapter.MyIconAdapterInterface {

  //change to iconIDTextList and change List data type
  List<IconData> iconIDTextList;
  IconAdapter iconAdapter;
  ListView listView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //istantiate my components
      iconIDTextList = new ArrayList<>();
      listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewIcon);
      //the second "this" is refer to the IconAdapter.MyIconAdapterInterface
      iconAdapter = new IconAdapter(this, iconIDTextList, this);
      int myIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background;
      String myText = "Hello! ";

      //populate the list with icon's id and text
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          iconIDTextList.add(new IconData(myIcon, myText + i));
      }

      //set my custom adapter to the listView
      listView.setAdapter(iconAdapter);

      //set clickListner to the elements of my listView
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

              //i is the index of the clicked element
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click on element n. " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      });

  }

  //this is IconAdapter.MyIconAdapterInterface's method that I have to implement
  @Override
  public void setOnClickListnerMyImageButton(int position) {

      //position = click's position
      Toast.makeText(this, "Click on image n. "
               + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
  ```

  }

Good Job!!

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much, it works perfectly